SignalerR negotiation version response is 0 but request is 1
Can you please help me to understand why the  version in response for my Signaler negotiation comes 0?  I send the negotiation version 1 as a request and as i check 100 times sampler and header is set up correctly, but i still receive 0 version as response

In header i have changed the content type parameter by several different values as text/plain;charset=UTF-8 but it did not work also

